# Re-sizable container with a snapshot positioned and resized in the center

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to have a container and set the background image for the container.
This container must be resizable when resizing the window.
Inside that container there are set of divs which have absolute positions and different z-indexes and assemble an snapshot of a car.
by re-sizing the window this bike also should re-size and stay in the center of that container.

```
<div class="col-lg-8 left-panel">
    <div class="resizable-container">
         <div class="resizable-wrapper">
            <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 0px;">
                <img src="...."/>
            </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 0px;">
                <img src="...."/>
            </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 0px;">
                <img src="...."/>
            </div>

         </div>
    </div>
</div>


.resizable-container{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 400px; (this height also should be resizable)
    background:  url('background.jpg');
}
.resizable-wrapper{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    /* margin: 0px auto; */
    top: -59px; (I have to do this to make the image position centered)
    left: -19%; (I have to do this to make the image position centered)
}
```

Can you guys help me please to achieve this? Do I need to write some script to set the height, top and left or I can do this purely using CSS. In both way I need your help. Thanks

here is the Jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7dsggjpo/3/

Comment: please create fiddle.

Comment: Your current code looks like: https://jsfiddle.net/7dsggjpo/

Comment: you can do all this ba `css` but by a little tricks.it's better to set fix height and width for your `resizable-wrapper` div, and handle the responsivity bye mediaquery.

Comment: I updated and created jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7dsggjpo/3/